# Unable to execute queries from Npgsql, even though I can connect to the database and generate a model through Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql, entity-framework-core, npgsql

I'm setting up a dev Postgres server for me to make an application for my team, however when I follow the tutorials on the NoSQL site I am unable to successfully interact with the database.

Here is the code I was using to try and connect. I removed all the async keywords from the code, because when I had them in, even with breakpoints the program would close before I could view the locals or see any exceptions.

```
private static void NPGSqlTest()
{
    var connectionString = @"host=localhost;database=dev;username=postgres;password=*******";
    string query = "SELECT * FROM table_test";

    using var dataSource = NpgsqlDataSource.Create(connectionString);
    using var command = dataSource.CreateCommand(query);
    using var reader = command.ExecuteReader();

    /*
    using NpgsqlConnection connection = dataSource.OpenConnection();
    using NpgsqlCommand command = new NpgsqlCommand(query, connection);
    using NpgsqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
    */

    Console.Read();
}
```

When I step through this code and get to the 'command' object, I get an exception `System.NotSupportedException` with the message

> Connection and transaction access is not supported on commands created from DbDataSource

This exception popped up under the "Connection", "DbConnection", "DbTransaction", and "Transaction" properties. The reader object gives no exceptions but shows having 0 rows.

Currently commented out I also tried opening the connection, which the docs say is the outdated way, and you should query directly against the dataSource, but that produced the same results.

My initial thought was I wasn't actually connecting to the database at all, but when I ran the command to scaffold the database for Entity Framework Core, that worked perfectly, and I was able to generate a model of the database with the same connection string parameters, so I don't think it's that.

My next thought was a version issue, perhaps. I am currently running on .NET 7 since one of the required libraries for this project is on .NET 7. I don't believe this is the issue however as I am running on the latest Npgsql 7.xxx for the core and all associated NuGet packages, and again, the EF Core command worked.

Finally, my thought is it is something to do with the PostgreSQL setup itself. I am just using the default superuser 'postgres' so I wouldn't think there would be any permission issues there. There may be another configuration thing elsewhere, but with my limited knowledge and searching of the Postgres docs, I haven't been able to find any answers.

Googling these errors hasn't provided yielded anything so far, so hopefully you guys have an answer.

Comment: Why not create an instance of your application DbContext and try a simple test that way: For example `using (var context = new AppDbContext(connectionString); bool IsConnected = context.Table_Tests.Any();` This will initialize the DbContext, establish a connection and report back whether any rows exist or throw an exception if there is a connection issue. (Assuming there is expected to be at least one row in the table, it will return false if the table is empty)

Comment: This error doesn't reproduce for me with the code you posted above - you probably left out the piece of code where you actually start a transaction. As the error message says, transactions aren't supported on commands that are created directly from the data source. There's nothing outdated about getting a connection from the data source and starting a transaction on it - you should definitely do that if you need a transaction (the "outdated thing" is to create a connection without using a data source at all).